# Migrating .NET Database to Shared Hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Built an app locally with an EF code-first database - not sure how to upload it to a shared hosting environment such as GoDaddy.  It makes sense that something would be amiss because on the shared hosting your code can't just go create a database, but on the flip side I can't find anything to copy the CREATE sql and create it on the server like you would with MySQL

Feel a little silly because I've been using .NET for over a year now but at work the databases are already set up and we have full control over our environments.

Answer (score 1):

If the database has no data that you need to preserve the easiest method is just to install the app on the new host and set the connection string to your new database on the host. On the first attempt to load a page accessing the database, the database will automatically be created (note that you need to load a page which hits the database - sometimes the home page is not sufficient).
This method is a lot more straightforward than generating SQL and then executing it on the production database.

If there is data that you need to preserve then the best method will be taking a backup and installing the backup on the host. In SSMS simply right-click the database in the left pane, then Tools > Backup... To restore on the server connect to the server in SSMS and right-click the 'Database' node in the left panel and select 'Restore Database...' I'm not sure if the host provides a direct connection from SSMS but they should at a minimum have a mechanism to restore a .bak file.

Going forward you should ensure that you can execute SQL on your database as a very convenient method for deploying EF Migrations is to generate the SQL update script on the development server and then deploy this by executing it in production.

Comment: If I understand correctly, though, code-first can't create a DB on shared hosting because you don't have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your web host, you may be able to restore the database. If this is an option, simply back up your database on your local machine and restore it on the server via the management console.

You can back up your local database using SQL Server Management Console. This works well even for larger databases as you can directly restore all your data, your schema, etc.

I've had experience with three different hosts so far and all of them have this as an option. You'll usually find this under the Database tab for the web site. The rest from there is up to you because it's usually different across the various hosts.